# New to Sublime Can't figure out snippets with javascript in them

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have just started using sublimeText2 since eclipse is really slow with large projects through a VPN.  I am trying to bring over some of my snippets.  Most are working ok but the follow one is a ajax call that I use but won't work as a snippet. I am guess that there are characters that need to be escaped or something but I am not sure which ones

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '.cfc',
        data: {method:''
            , var: var
            , var2:var
                },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            var result = jQuery.trim(result);
            console.log(result);
            } 
        }
    });     

]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ajax</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you able to accept your answer so the question goes into the correct queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to escape the $ with \$ and it works

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

    \$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '.cfc',
        data: {method:''
            , var: var
            , var2:var
                },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            var result = jQuery.trim(result);
            console.log(result);
            } 
        }
    });     

]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>ajax</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `CDATA` tag enclosure causes this problem? Just a guess...

Comment: Nope the closure was working I had tried it plain text.  Turns out you have to escape the $.  Thanks for looking though!