# Sublime Text 2 Snippet returning blank

Tags: sublimetext2

When I call the snippet below I get blank content instead of the code saved in the snippet. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? If I replace the code with a string like "foobar" the string displays when I call the snippet. So it seems I'm missing something.

```
<snippet>
    <content>
<![CDATA[

$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml/html/script/json/jsonp',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});

]]>
</content>
<tabTrigger>ajax</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Comment: duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961566/new-to-sublime-cant-figure-out-snippets-with-javascript-in-them?rq=1

You need to escape the '$'

Answer (score 1):

Just escape your jquery call

```
<snippet>
    <content>
<![CDATA[

\$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml/html/script/json/jsonp',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});

]]>
</content>
<tabTrigger>ajax</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```